# How to display data from Jekyll data file based on current page variable

Tags: for-loop, yaml, jekyll, liquid

### The Problem

I have a `div` on my Jekyll site where I would like to display data that is generated from `_data/book-data.yml`, for example:

```
- name: johnson-everything-under
  title: Everything Under
  author: Daisy Johnson
  publisher: Faber & Faber
  pub-date: 12/12/2012

- name: johnson-train-dreams
  title: Train Dreams
  author: Denis Johsnon
  publisher: Granta
  pub-date: 01/01/2001
```

I'm trying to find a way to display the data that corresponds to the relevant page (each book entry has a different page), and I thought maybe this would be possible if the `name` key corresponds to the `page.url`, or some other page variable.

### What I've tried

On a working page, I have an `include` which contains the following HTML:

```
<div class="book-meta">
  {% if page.category == "reviews"%}
  <div class="book-thumbnail">
    <img class="post-thumbnail-lg" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/{{ page.thumbnail }}" alt="{{ page.thumbnail }}">
  </div>
  {% for book in site.data.book-data %}
  <div class="book-details">
    <ul class="book-meta-list">
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p><a href="#">{{ book.author }}</a></p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p><em>{{ book.title }}</em></p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p>{{ book.publisher }}</p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p>{{ book.pub-date }}</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

The CSS is not important, but as it is currently the output of the above HTML is:

[image: Screenshot]

### Desired output

As you can see, the output contains both the blocks of metadata from the `.yml` file. I would like to find a way so that only the relevant block of data (the first block in this instance) is displayed:

[image: Screenshot2]

### Potential solution(s)

I thought that there might be a way of matching a `page.variable` to the YAML block name so only the right book data gets output. Something along the lines of:

```
{% assign url_substring = page.url | split, '/' | last %}
// url_substring = johnson-everything-under
{% for book in site.data.book-data %}
{% if url_substring == book.name %}
// = true
<p>{{ book.title }}<p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Other than the fact that I can't get this to work properly, I can also see that the liquid tag `{{ book.title }}` has no way of knowing which book title to output, even if the `page.url` matches.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here, so if anyone has any other suggestions on how this might be achievable, I'd love to hear it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jekyll's `where` filter coupled with a smart include:

```html
{% assign book = site.data.book-data | where: 'title', include.title | first %}

<div class="book-meta">
  <div class="book-thumbnail">
    <img
      class="post-thumbnail-lg"
      src="{{ book.thumbnail | prepend: 'assets/images/' | relative_url }}"
      alt="{{ book.title }}"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="book-details">
    <ul class="book-meta-list">
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p><a href="#">{{ book.author }}</a></p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p><em>{{ book.title }}</em></p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p>{{ book.publisher }}</p></li>
      <li class="book-meta-item"><p>{{ book.pub-date }}</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note that I also included `thumbnail` info in the data file..*

Then just pass the `title` parameter to the include (in the layout for your book's page):

```
{% include books.html title = 'Everything Under' %}
```

If you'd like to render a "listing", then just loop through and render:

```
{% for book in site.data.book-data %}
  {% include books.html title = book.title %}
{% endfor %}
```